# Does Linux WiFi regulatory domain consider antenna gain?

Tags: linux-kernel, wifi

I am currently trying to verify whether a wifi device is violating broadcast regulations or not and stumbled upon an question that was asked here before but never answered ( https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/24504 ).

> Where things become unclear for me is how the antenna gain is
> accounted for in the configuration (I have never researched this
> thoroughly, so the answer is probably out there). The adapter can't
> detect the gain of an antenna, so this should be configured or
> accounted for somewhere.
>
> As an example if you are legally allowed to transmit at 100mW,
> iwconfig will typically show a TX power of 20dBm (100mW). However the
> antenna gain is added to this, so if you have a 3dBi antenna, this
> would result in a TX power of 23dBm or 200mW. With this 3dBi antenna,
> the radio TX power should be set to 17dBm to match the allowed 100mW
> TX power.
>
> If iwconfig assumes a certain type of antenna (possibly based on
> adapter type?), you may be required to reduce the radio TX power if
> you use a higher gain antenna.

Does setting a CRDA regulatory domain somehow consider the antenna gain when setting the tx power of the wifi module? I would think that that has to be the case. Otherwise a lot of devices would violate broadcast regulations. If the maximum antenna gain is configured somewhere, can I read it to check if the currently installed antenna is within this limit?

Thanks

Comment: Just a note on context: If you are trying to verify that something is legally sellable in a particular country then you will most likely need to have it tested and certified by a specialist.  Having been through the process for a non-wifi SBC it's surprising which off the shelf devices are non-compliant.

Comment: @Philip Couling Thanks. Compliance Testing in a certified laboratory is something we are planning to do but we would like to check what we can check ourselves to minimize the time/attempts there. And yes. The longer I am looking into this the more I wonder whether anything is actually 100% within the regulation.